# trying to write a nested ordinal regression

Tags: regression

I have a data set

[image]

I wanted to predict what profile (ordinal data) students will fall into based on whether they failed a test (without too much detail the values of fail are 0 and 1 and being considered numeric) and a value based on sentiment scoring of performance comments which is the colum value (interval data from -5 to 5).  each B line id identifies a unique student but there are multiple values for each blineid for example:

[image]

how can I account for this nested structure in my code

afinnR$profile<-factor(afinnR$profile, levels = c("3", "4", "1", "2"))

model<-vglm(profile ~ fail * value + fail+ value, multinomial(refLevel = 1), data = afinnR)
summary(model)